# How do I turn a RoR view to Responsive (html5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html, layout, responsive-design

I have a normal view in html in Rails, containing images and links. How do I turn it to be responsive? (I want it to fit also mobile browser sizes, make it html5) 
I know I should use `fluid`, but what is the full command? Or is there another/better way directly from the text editor?

Comment: This has nothing to do with rails, and everything to do with the CSS that you are using.

Comment: Are you assuming the use of the Twitter Bootstrap UI framework? You may want to realign this question to be about "how to use Bootstrap within Rails to create a responsive layout", if so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails has limited control on the HTML that comes on to the browse.

Try looking at frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

There are some gems that can help you

- [Foundation-rails](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails)
- [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails)

There is also a railscast episode on [Bootstrap basics](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics).

Comment: I plan on using bootstrap, thanks! but in the meanwhile I wanted to throw some things on the browser

Comment: @LucyWeatherford - have included some more resources to wire up bootstrap and rails.

Comment: Thanks, I see here how I can add bootstrap to a completely new application. How do I delete the current stylesheets etc from an existing application so I can install bootstrap and not have any conflicts?

Comment: @LucyWeatherford - That I would say is a manual task. If you start with your layout file, it should lead you to all CSS references (unless you have styles injected elsewhere). Another option is to do a grep to gather all the references and remove them.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing much to do with Rails. Rails is a server side language and responsive templates are frontend (html/css) dependent.

However if you are specifically using bootstrap as many beginners do, you could try : https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails gem for a quick integration of things.